Pull effect when at end of overscroll element
How to achieve in CSS that pull effect when reaching the end of the content of a scrollable container?
I was browsing my website on mobile, and I am frustrated when at the end of the horizontal scroll container, nothing happens when dragging a finger on the screen.
Effects (gif rel) from Instagram or even ads on YouTube are amazing, and they are giving a clear indication to the user that the end was reached.
If it's not achievable from plain CSS, then JavaScript is welcome as well.

